# How to eliminate outer reference from subquery

Tags: sql-server, reference, subquery, outer-join

I have a query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A2P.p_year [Year], A2P.aid [CoAuthor] 
FROM sub_aminer_author2paper A2P
WHERE pid IN (
               SELECT A2P.pid 
               FROM sub_aminer_author2paper A2P
               JOIN sub_aminer_paper P ON A2P.pid = P.pid
               WHERE DATALENGTH(P.p_abstract) > 0 AND
               A2P.aid IN (
                            SELECT aid 
                            FROM Authors
                          ) AND A2P.p_year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2014
             )
AND A2P.aid NOT IN (
                     SELECT aid 
                     FROM Authors
                   )
ORDER BY Year, CoAuthor
```

This query gives me output as:

```
Year    CoAuthor
2005    796
2005    947
2005    1032
2005    1740
2005    1960
2005    4045
2005    4472 
...  
...
```

Whereas I want to have output as:

```
Author   Year   CoAuthor   Venue
677      2005   796        234565
677      2005   947        127634
677      2005   1032       235487
1359     2005   1740       341265
1359     2005   1960       23658
1359     2005   4045       3412
1359     2005   4472       235473
...  
...
```

The column which I add manually are the `aid`'s from part of query i.e. `SELECT aid FROM Authors`. How can it be selected ? Whereas I'm also using `A2P.aid NOT IN (SELECT aid FROM Authors)` because I don't want to display `Author` in `CoAuthor` column.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner The extra added column i.e. `Venue` is in another table named `sub_aminer_paper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you simply want to list all author / co-author teams per year. When selecting from sub_aminer_author2paper you already have all authors and co-authors, but you must determine who is who and who worked with whom. In order to do so use a cte (a WITH clause) and select twice from it:

```
with a2p as
(
  select 
    aid, pid, p_year, 
    case when aid in (select aid from authors) then 'author' else 'co-author' end as what
  from sub_aminer_author2paper
  where p_year between 2005 and 2014
  and pid in (select pid from sub_aminer_paper where datalength(p_abstract) > 0)
)
select distinct a.aid as [Author], a.p_year as [Year], c.aid as [CoAuthor] 
from (select * from a2p where what = 'author') a
join (select * from a2p where what = 'co-author') c on c.pid = a.pid
order by ...;
```

Comment: @Thorsten---Thanks you much!

Comment: @Thorsten--If I want to add another column in output as shown above, then how your query will be modified